# Detecting which button was pressed

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to detect which was button was pressed with jQuery and then server-side do different things depending on the outcome.

The jQuery works fine (although I may have gone about it in a long- handed way) but I can't figure out why in my code whichever button I press I get the same response from php: *"Add button detected"*. I hope someone can tell me what I've got wrong?

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn_add").on("click", function() { //If add btn pressed
        var id = this.id;
        var url = "process_ajax4.php?btn=" + this.id;

        var formdata = $('.myForm').serialize();
        $.post(url, formdata,
            function(data) {

                $("#results").html(data); //Response


            });
    });
    $(".btn_remove").on("click", function() { //If remove btn pressed
        var id = this.id;
        var url = "process_ajax4.php?btn=" + this.id;

        var formdata = $('.myForm').serialize();
        $.post(url, formdata,
            function(data) {

                $("#results").html(data); //Response

            });
    });

});
```

The Php

```
<?php
$btn=$_POST["btn"]; //Other posted variables removed for simplicity

if($btn="btn_add"){

    echo "<h1>Add button detected</h1>";
//Do stuff

}
elseif($btn="btn_remove"){

    echo "<h1>Remove button detected</h1>";
//Do other stuff
}
?>
```

The html Form

```
<td>
    <form id=\ "myForm\" class=\ "myForm\" action=\ "\" method=\ "post\" enctype=\ "multipart/form-data\">
        <input type=\ "hidden\" name=\ "user_id\" value=". $collab_userid." />
        <input type=\ "hidden\" name=\ "id\" value=".$upload_id." />

        <button type=\ "submit\" id=\ "btn_remove\" class=\ "btn_remove\" name=\ "btn_remove\">Remove</button>
        <button type=\ "submit\" id=\ "btn_add\" class=\ "btn_add\" name=\ "btn_add\">Approve</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: you are comparing strings with `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the pressed button to your `formdata`, otherwise the click couldn't be detected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn_add").on("click", function() { //If add btn pressed
        var id = this.id;
        var url = "process_ajax4.php?btn=" + this.id;

        var formdata = $('.myForm').serialize();
        formdata += "&btn=btn_add"; // added the btn
        $.post(url, formdata,
            function(data) {

                $("#results").html(data); //Response


            });
    });
    $(".btn_remove").on("click", function() { //If remove btn pressed
        var id = this.id;
        var url = "process_ajax4.php?btn=" + this.id;

        var formdata = $('.myForm').serialize();
        formdata += "&btn=btn_remove"; // added the btn
        $.post(url, formdata,
            function(data) {

                $("#results").html(data); //Response

            });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change php code as follows**

```
<?php
    $btn=$_POST["btn"]; //Other posted variables removed for simplicity

    if ($btn=="btn_add") {
       echo "<h1>Add button detected</h1>";
    //Do stuff
    } elseif ($btn=="btn_remove"){
       echo "<h1>Remove button detected</h1>";
    //Do other stuff
    }


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You **need not have two separate** function for `jquery button` handling. Also you can remove the `button type="submit"` from your code since you are detecting the click event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() { //If add btn pressed
        var id = this.id;
      
        var url = "process_ajax4.php?btn=" + this.id;
        console.log(url);
        var formdata = $('.myForm').serialize();
        $.post(url, formdata,
            function(data) {

                $("#results").html(data); //Response


            });
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
    <form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="\" method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=". $collab_userid." />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value=".$upload_id." />

        <button  type="submit" id="btn_remove" class="btn_remove" name= "btn_remove">Remove</button>
        <button  id="btn_add" class= "btn_add" name="btn_add">Approve</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

You can use the `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` for getting the query string in php. In order to use `$btn=$_POST["btn"];` tbn attribute must be passed as a form data, query parameters wont will be available through this method

```
<?php
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$btn =  $query['btn'];

if($btn=="btn_add"){

    echo "<h1>Add button detected</h1>";
//Do stuff

}
elseif($btn=="btn_remove"){

    echo "<h1>Remove button detected</h1>";
//Do other stuff
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just make `var url = process_ajax4.php` that will fix your problem.in `PHP` use `==` instead of `=`, also add `e.preventDefault()` to your button clicks to prevent the form from being submitted with `action='url'`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn_add").on("click", function(e) { //If add btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var url = "process_ajax4.php";

    var formdata = $('.myForm').serialize();
    formdata += "&btn=btn_add"; // added the btn
    $.post(url, formdata,
        function(data) {

            $("#results").html(data); //Response


        });
});
$(".btn_remove").on("click", function(e) { //If remove btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var url = "process_ajax4.php";

    var formdata = $('.myForm').serialize();
    formdata += "&btn=btn_remove"; // added the btn
    $.post(url, formdata,
        function(data) {

            $("#results").html(data); //Response

        });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your code looks ok.

i think in php you cannot compare string by =
you may need to change it to strcmp(strA,strB)==0 in order to ensure the input parameter is add button or remove button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the jQuery code at all. Since both `btn_remove` and `btn_add` are submit buttons, you can check which of the buttons where used to submit the form by using:

```
if(isset($_POST["btn_remove"])) {
     //Remove button was pressed.
}
```